# mod_perl server events for client

Tags: web-services, perl, apache, soap, mod-perl

What is a good way to implement server to client callbacks (events) with a web service?

We already have a SOAP-based API exposed by mod_perl running on Apache, but it is one way client to server.  We need to notify the client of certain changes on the server by other clients.

What is a good way to make this work?  Available modules for perl?

One thing we thought of was to make a long running web request that would finally respond when an event occurred, but this would seem to keep too many mod_perl processes running if many clients were connected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is the one you mentioned, long-running polls.

The other is [websockets](http://websocket.org/). There are many Perl frameworks which are able to deal with websockets requests, one of which is [Mojolicious](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Mojolicious).

See the docs at [Mojolicious::Lite#WebSockets](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Mojolicious/lib/Mojolicious/Lite.pm#WebSockets) for some examples.

I would suggest in your case running the websockets webapp separately from the mod_perl server, and "just" using Apache to reverse-proxy the mojolicious app.

Comment: Just a couple notes: like the OP asked, long-running polls are bad for scalability since they will tie a single apache process up for that single client for the duration of the poll. Also, web sockets are really new and not available in all clients. Another alternative that uses existing browser tech is Comet, but that requires a different type of server to be scalable: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually tried your first approach ? How many max concurrent clients would that be? A few dozens should be manageable by apache. Just guessing.

Have you tried this low-tech method ["Watching long processes through CGI"](http://www.stonehenge.com/merlyn/LinuxMag/col39.html), or is it what you wanted to get rid of in the first place?

Comment: There would usually be around 100-200 users on the system, but they could possibly have ~10 or so client applications receiving events on multiple PCs.  We would rather account for high usage beforehand, as to prevent issues in the future.